# Pandas merge indexing not behaving as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to perform an anti-join in effectively one line.  However, my one line solution is not giving me the same results that a receive when breaking up the code into two lines (which behaves as expected).  Specifically, the single-line solution results in a dataframe with fewer rows.

The goal of my anti-join is to remove any overlap of the UNIQUE_IDs of `df` and `df_subset1`.  The result will be `df_subset2`.

Single line:

```
df_subset2 = df.loc[df.merge(df_subset1['UNIQUE_ID'], on = 'UNIQUE_ID', how = 'outer', indicator = True)._merge == 'left_only']
```

Multi line:

```
df_subset2 = df.merge(df_subset1['UNIQUE_ID'], on = 'UNIQUE_ID', how = 'outer', indicator = True)
df_subset2 = df_subset2.loc[df_subset2._merge == 'left_only']
```

These yield different results, but from my perspective the single line should still work as intended.  Does merging change the index of the underlying dataframe?  That would be the only reason I can think of which would cause the `.loc` operation to select differently.

Comment: The result of `df.merge` has different size (number of rows) especially when you use 'outer' join.  For your case, would it be better if you use left join instead of outer join ?

Comment: Got it -- so it sounds like `merge` changes the index which causes `.loc` to behave differently.  I can't do a left join here because I am specifically trying to remove overlap with the right dataframe.  That's why I'm using the indicator and selecting where `_merge == 'left_only'`

Comment: In that case, try to chain your call with `.query()` call.  See details below.  Haven't had a chance to test it out coz without your test data.  But you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get one-line solution, you can try chaining your `df.merge()` call with a [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) call like below:

```
df_subset2 = df.merge(df_subset1['UNIQUE_ID'], on = 'UNIQUE_ID', how = 'outer', indicator = True).query('_merge == "left_only"')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  I had totally forgotten about the `query` method ... will definitely be using this more moving forward